# Angular: ngView and functions not working right away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

On my website, if you scroll down to the third section that says "Victorious Gaming" and hover over the arrows on the left and right, no text shows up.  However, the second time and thereafter you hover over the arrows, the text correctly shows up.  Why do they not work the very first time?  The same applies to when you hover over the text "Victorious Gaming"

In my Controller, I have:

```
projectApp.controller("featuredController", ["$rootScope", "$scope", function ($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.leftArrow = function(){
      $(function(){
        $(".left-arrow a").hover(function(){

          $('.left-info').css('opacity','1');

        }, function(){
           $('.left-info').css('opacity','0');

        });
      });
    };
    $scope.rightArrow = function(){
      $(function(){
        $(".right-arrow a").hover(function(){

          $('.right-info').css('opacity','1');

        }, function(){
           $('.right-info').css('opacity','0');

        });
      });
    };

$scope.bigWords = function(){

       $(function(){
  $(".big-word-padding").hover(
      function() {
    $('.blur-background').fadeOut(700);
    $('.big-word-padding').find('h2').css('color','blue');
    $('.color-blue').css('color','white');

  }, function() {
    $('.blur-background').fadeIn(300);
     $('.big-word-padding').find('h2').css('color','white');
     $('.color-blue').css('color','blue');

  });
    $(".big-word-padding").hover(
      function() {
    $('.blur-background').fadeOut(700);
    $('.big-word-padding').find('.m-title').css('color','white');
     $('.big-word-padding').find('#manga-title').addClass('textShadowM');
     $('.big-word-padding').find('.m-title').addClass('textShadowManga');
    $('.color-blue').css('color','white');

  }, function() {
    $('.blur-background').fadeIn(300);
     $('.big-word-padding').find('.m-title').css('color','rgb(26, 107, 156)');
$('.big-word-padding').find('#manga-title').removeClass('textShadowM');
     $('.big-word-padding').find('.m-title').removeClass('textShadowManga');
     $('.color-blue').css('color','blue');

  });
});
};
}]);
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="ng-container" ng-controller="featuredController">
<div ng-view class="view-animate">

</div>
</div>
```

External HTML file(templates/featured-proj.html):

```
  <div class="big-feature">
    <div class="big-background second-background"></div>
    <div class="blur-background second-background"></div>
    <div class="big-word">
      <div class="big-word-padding" ng-mouseover="bigWords()">
      <h2> Victorious <span class="color-blue">Gaming</span></h2>
      <h3>UI Developer. Design.</h3>
      <hr>
      <a href="http://league.victoriousgaming.com/landing" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" id="arrow-project"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-arrow">
        <a href="#/feature3" ng-mouseover="leftArrow()"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

    </div>
     <div class="left-info">
        My Art
      </div>
    <div class="right-arrow">
        <a href="#/feature2" ng-mouseover="rightArrow()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

    </div>
        <div class="right-info">
        Mangahere
      </div>
<!--      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="#/feature"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/feature2"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/feature3"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
      </ul> -->



      <div class="info-vic">
        <div class="row-vic">
            <div class="left-vic"></div>
            <div class="right-vic"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-vic">
            <div class="left-vic"></div>
            <div class="right-vic"></div>
        </div>
                <div class="row-vic">
            <div class="left-vic"></div>
            <div class="right-vic"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

And my config for routing:

```
 projectApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/feature', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/featured-proj.html'
      })

      // route for the about page
      .when('/feature2', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/featured-proj-2.html'
      })

      // route for the contact page
      .when('/feature3', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/featured-proj-3.html'
      })
       .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/feature' } );
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have an extra `$(function(){ ... })` wrapper both in `leftArrow()` and `rightArrow()`.

In addition, the hover effect gets set only when when those functions are called for the first time. During that call, the opacity will not be modified.

I would replace `ng-mouseover="leftArrow()"` with `ng-mouseenter="leftArrowShow()" ng-mouseleave="leftArrowHide()"` and then define these functions like:

```
$scope.leftArrowShow = function() {
    $('.left-info').addClass('show');
};
$scope.leftArrowHide = function() {
    $('.left-info').removeClass('show');
};
```

And then, in CSS, have:

```
.left-info.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

`rightArrow()` would be handled in a similar manner.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I haven't been able to find out the reason for so long >.<, by the way, do you happen to know the answer to my bonus question by any chance?  It's off-topic so I'll probably create another thread for it but if you have time, I would be so thankful :)